# Shift in position and orientation in the SVG image when saved using firefox 25

Tags: firefox, svg, transform

i am trying migrate our application to support the latest version of firefox (V25).

**Functionality:**

We are using lot of rotated text div's and rotated images. Once the user clicks on save button all these rotated text div's and images will be converted in to an image using SVG.

**Issue:**

The problem with firefox25 is, the rotated elements in the SVG are shifting from its original position and not maintaing its orientation.

i am using html2canvas for SVG part

After researching for few hours, i figured that the following could be the reason.

figure 1
When i am inspecting rotated div in firefox 10 using firebug, it highlights exactly the rotated div
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK0ev.jpg

figure 2
When i am inspecting rotated div using firebug, it doesn't highlight the rotated div. the shift that i am seeing in the SVG is equivalent to the highlighted area.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwFO6.jpg

But i have no clue on how to fix it!!

i do not see any problem with square shape elements i only see this problem with rectangular div's.

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: i couldn't give theese links in my OP as i do not have 10 reputation http://imgur.com/cn1tgvJ and http://imgur.com/0375BkE

Comment: Create a complete but simple testcase we can run to see what's happening

Comment: Thanks Robert for the quick reply!! Here's is quick example that i can give to make you understand. I found this w3school example http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/trycss3_transform-origin_inuse.htm. please try to enter this url here [link](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/screenshots.html) and observe the shift at the top left corner of the red box.

Comment: Looks exactly the same in Opera 12 and Firefox 25. There's a transform origin set so it's rotating round that.